# Gridview using objectdatasource displays too many pages

Tags: c#, gridview, paging, objectdatasource

I have a gridview using an objectdatasource that whenever it has multiple pages to display, it displays one more than than it should. When the user selects that page the EmptyDataTemplate is displayed. I'm not doing anything special in the databinding so I'm not sure what would cause this behavior. Is there a workaround or fix for this?

Comment: Did you allready try to debug and look into the data of your objectdatasource?

Comment: I'm not sure how the data matters? The data is being returned just fine, the gridview is just giving it an extra unnecessary page.

Comment: Well, wouldn't be too much effort to exclude that the data has e.g. a trailing null value.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand how a trailing null value could lead to an additional page? Are pages not related to the number of rows? There are also no null values in this dataset.

Comment: This was what i wanted you to ensure. That the last row is not empty and therefore leading to an empty page.